# JavaScript NextElementSibling not working

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, html-input

I have several Javascript inputs inside of  elements, and s below them.

I also have a javascript function which wipes the value of the input if there is a letter input into it, so that it only accepts numbers.

```js
t=function(elem){
elem.onkeyup=function(e) {
  if(!/[\d\.]/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which))) {
    elem.value='';
    x=elem.nextElementSibling;
    x.innerHTML='invalid string';
  }
};
};
```

```html
<dt>
  <input type='number' onkeyup='t(this)'/>
 </dt>
<dd>
  text
  </dd>
<dt>
  <input type='number' onkeyup='t(this)'/>
  </dt>
<dd>
  text
  </dd>
<!--comment-->

As you can see, if you type a letter into either input, it clears that input.
```

As you can see, if you enter a letter into eithr input, it clears that input. I would like to change the innerHTML of the following

```
<dd></dd>
```

element to 'invalid character', and you can see my attempt to do this on javascript lines 5 and 6. Why isn't this working? Any ideas? Know a fix?

Regular/pure javascript answers only, please.

Comment: `nextElementSibling` refers to the ... well, next element _sibling_. The inputs in your code don't have siblings.

Comment: Your inputs have no siblings, they're only childs

Answer (score 3):

You want to access: `elem.parentNode.nextElementSibling` because you are looking for the sibling of `<dt>` (the parent element), and not `<input>` which has no siblings.

```js
t=function(elem){
elem.onkeyup=function(e) {
  if(!/[\d\.]/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which))) {
    elem.value='';
    x=elem.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
    x.innerHTML='invalid string';
  }
};
};
```

```html
<dt>
  <input type='number' onkeyup='t(this)'/>
 </dt>
<dd>
  text
  </dd>
<dt>
  <input type='number' onkeyup='t(this)'/>
  </dt>
<dd>
  text
  </dd>
```